# Post more than one parameter for file upload to the web api

Tags: javascript

I have this html form which let user upload a file and also another extra input type for extra info about this upload.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input id="files" name="files" type="file" size="1" />           
       <input type="text" id="tags">           
       <button type="submit" id="btnSave" onchange="uploadFiles();">Upload and Save</button>        
</form>
```

and this is my javascript

```
function uploadFiles() {
    var input = document.getElementById('files');
    var files = input.files;
    var formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("files", files[i]);
    }

    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "https://localhost:xxx/api/file/upload",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function () {
                alert("Files Uploaded!");

            }
        }
    );
}
```

My question is how do I add others parameters (i.e tags here) to post to web api and at the same time upload the file? Post the request at complex type? Any example for complex type which include file upload?

Comment: formData.append("tags",document.getelementbyid('tags').value);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can append new properties there.
formdata append will help you to add string and file

```
formData.append("tags",document.getelementbyid('tags').value);
```

this is some source to read about FormData
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData